# How can I add the item to cart page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to add the items to a cart page when a user clicks the add to cart button.

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function ItemDetail(handleClick) {
  const params = useParams();
  let { productCode, vendor, value}  = params;
  let item = {productCode, vendor, value};

  console.log(item);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p>product id: {productCode}</p>
        <p>price: {value}</p>
        <p>vendor: {vendor}</p>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick(item)}>Add to Cart</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default ItemDetail;
```

This is the cart page. Where I am to, render the item details from **Item Details** Page.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Cart = ({ cart, setCart, handleChange }) => {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);

  const handleRemove = (id) => {
    const arr = cart.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    setCart(arr);
    handlePrice();
  };

  const handlePrice = () => {
    let ans = 0;
    cart.map((item) => (ans += item.amount * item.price));
    setPrice(ans);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handlePrice();
  });

  console.log(setCart);

  return (
    <article>
      {cart.map((item) => (
        <div className="cart_box" key={item.id}>
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => handleChange(item, 1)}>+</button>
            <button>{item.amount}</button>
            <button onClick={() => handleChange(item, -1)}>-</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>{item.price}</span>
            <button onClick={() => handleRemove(item.id)}>Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <div className="total">
        <span>Total Price of your Cart</span>
        <span>R - {price}</span>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

This is my item description page. I have fetched the items using params, this is only way I found easier for me.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import StyledCard from "../components/Card";

const Discover = (props, params, handleClick) => {
  const token = "not-the-actual-token";
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/product/",
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      }
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setResult(json));
  }, []);

  const cardStyle = {
    listStyle: "none",
    margin: 5,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    minWidth: 240,
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="latestdeals container my-5">
        <h1>All Products</h1>
        <Row className="hotcards">
          <Col className="colcard">
            {(result?.result || []).map((item) => (
              <div key={item.productCode} style={cardStyle}>
                <a href={`/itemDetail/${item.productCode}/${item.value}/${item.vendor}`}>
                  {" "}
                  <StyledCard
                    key={item.productCode}
                    name={item.vendor}
                    title={item.description}
                    price={item.value}
                    handleClick={handleClick}
                    item={item}
                  />
                </a>
              </div>
            ))}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Discover;
```

This is my App page

```
import "./index.scss";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";
import AllCategories from "./pages/all-catergories";
import Home from "./pages/home";
import Entertainment from "./pages/entertainment";
// import Cart from "./pages/_cart";
import Login from "./pages/login";
import Netflix from "./pages/netflix";
import Orders from "./pages/orders";
import SignUp from "./pages/sign-up";
// import Data2 from "./Data2";
import Products from "./pages/products";
// import Shop from "./components/Shop";
// import ProductDetail from "./pages/ProductDetail";
import Discover from "./pages/discover";
import ItemDetail from "./pages/itemDetail";
import Cart from "./pages/cart";

function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (item) => {
    if (cart.indexOf(item) !== -1) return;
    setCart([...cart, item]);
  };

  const handleChange = (item, d) => {
    const ind = cart.indexOf(item);
    const arr = cart;
    arr[ind].amount += d;

    if (arr[ind].amount === 0) arr[ind].amount = 1;
    setCart([...arr]);
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="all-categories" exact element={<AllCategories />} />
        {/* <Route path="cart" exact element={<Cart />} /> */}
        <Route path="entertainment" exact element={<Entertainment />} />
        <Route path="login" exact element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="discover" exact element={<Discover />} />
        <Route path="netflix" exact element={<Netflix />} />
        <Route path="orders" exact element={<Orders />} />
        <Route path="sign-up" exact element={<SignUp />} />
        <Route path="products" element={<Products />} />
        <Route path="/itemDetail/:productCode/:value/:vendor" element={<ItemDetail />} />
        <Route path="/itemDetail/" element={<ItemDetail handleClick={handleClick}  />} />
        <Route path="/Cart/" exact element={<Cart cart={cart} setCart={setCart} handleChange={handleChange}/>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is currently not working in your code? Do you get an error?

Comment: When I click the button no information is passed to the cart page

Comment: `function ItemDetail(handleClick)` is incorrect. The first (and only) parameter of a React function component is an object that contains all parameters you sent to the component. Thus, you should change it to `function ItemDetail(params)`, and then change the button's onclick to look like this: `<button onClick={() => params.handleClick(item)}>`.

Comment: I can not do that, because Params has already been declared.

Comment: Then call it something else, for example `func_params`. The important thing is that you change the onclick: `<button onClick={() => func_params.handleClick(item)}>`

Comment: Hi, I have tried that. There is no luck.

Comment: You've issues declaring React components, several of them aren't using props correctly. `function ItemDetail(handleClick) { ... }` should be `function ItemDetail({ handleClick }) { ... }`, and `const Discover = (props, params, handleClick) => { ... }` should probably be something like `const Discover = ({ params, handleClick, ...props }) => { ... }`. React components receive a single props object argument.

Comment: I have corrected them to the same syntax. In the cart file I am not sure how I can map the data, I have tried using cart.map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issues

You've issues declaring React components, several of them aren't using props correctly. `function ItemDetail(handleClick) { ... }` should be `function ItemDetail({ handleClick }) { ... }`, and `const Discover = (props, params, handleClick) => { ... }` should probably be something like `const Discover = ({ params, handleClick, ...props }) => { ... }`. React components receive a single props object argument.

`handleChange` in `App` is also mutating state.

## Solution

### App

Fix the state mutation and ensure props are passed correctly to routed components. Use an item GUID to search the cart instead of shallow reference equality when checking to add to the cart. When updating cart quantities it is necessary to shallow copy the cart array and cart items that are being updated. Use functional state updates whenever possible so it's ensured it's updating from the previous state and not any stale state value closed over in scope.

```
function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (item) => {
    // Update cart item quantity if already in cart
    if (cart.some((cartItem) => cartItem.productCode === item.productCode)) {
      setCart((cart) =>
        cart.map((cartItem) =>
          cartItem.productCode === item.productCode
            ? {
                ...cartItem,
                amount: cartItem.amount + 1
              }
            : cartItem
        )
      );
      return;
    }

    // Add to cart
    setCart((cart) => [
      ...cart,
      { ...item, amount: 1 } // <-- initial amount 1
    ]);
  };

  const handleChange = (productCode, d) => {
    setCart((cart) =>
      cart.flatMap((cartItem) =>
        cartItem.productCode === productCode
          ? cartItem.amount + d < 1
            ? [] // <-- remove item if amount will be less than 1
            : [
                {
                  ...cartItem,
                  amount: cartItem.amount + d
                }
              ]
          : [cartItem]
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="all-categories" element={<AllCategories />} />
        <Route path="entertainment" element={<Entertainment />} />
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="discover" element={<Discover />} />
        <Route path="netflix" element={<Netflix />} />
        <Route path="orders" element={<Orders />} />
        <Route path="sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
        <Route path="products" element={<Products />} />
        <Route
          path="/itemDetail/:productCode/:value/:vendor"
          element={<ItemDetail handleClick={handleClick} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/Cart/"
          element={(
            <Cart
              cart={cart}
              setCart={setCart}
              handleChange={handleChange}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

### ItemDetail

Access/destructure the `handleClick` prop correctly. Pass the item's `productCode` to the callback.

```
function ItemDetail({ handleClick }) {
  const { productCode, vendor, value} = useParams();
  const item = { productCode, vendor, value };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>product id: {productCode}</p>
      <p>price: {value}</p>
      <p>vendor: {vendor}</p>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(item)}>Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Discover

Correctly access/destructure the `handleClick` callback. Use the `Link` component instead of the raw anchor (`<a />`) tag. The anchor tag will reload the app which very likely isn't what you want to happen. Based on the code I suspect you don't actually need this `handleClick` since the `ItemDetail` component is passed it and adds to the cart

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const cardStyle = {
  listStyle: "none",
  margin: 5,
  paddingLeft: 0,
  minWidth: 240,
};

const Discover = () => {
  const token = "not-the-actual-token";
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/product/",
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      }
    )
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not OK');
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => setResult(data.result))
      .catch(error => {
        // handle any rejected Promises, errors, etc...
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="latestdeals container my-5">
      <h1>All Products</h1>
      <Row className="hotcards">
        <Col className="colcard">
          {result.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.productCode} style={cardStyle}>
              <Link to={`/itemDetail/${item.productCode}/${item.value}/${item.vendor}`}>
                <StyledCard
                  name={item.vendor}
                  title={item.description}
                  price={item.value}
                  item={item}
                />
              </Link>
            </div>
          ))}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Cart

Don't store the cart total in state, it is easily derived from the `cart` state.

```
const Cart = ({ cart, setCart, handleChange }) => {
  const handleRemove = (productCode) => {
    setCart(cart => cart.filter(item => item.productCode !== productCode));
  };

  const price = cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.amount * item.price, 0);

  return (
    <article>
      {cart.map((item) => (
        <div className="cart_box" key={item.id}>
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => handleChange(item.productCode, 1)}>+</button>
            <button>{item.amount}</button>
            <button onClick={() => handleChange(item.productCode, -1)}>-</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>{item.price}</span>
            <button onClick={() => handleRemove(item.productCode)}>Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <div className="total">
        <span>Total Price of your Cart</span>
        <span>R - {price}</span>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-add-the-item-to-cart-page-in-react]

Comment: Failed to understand Drew

Comment: @manassehcoder Sorry, can you clarify what/where the failure to understand is? Have I misunderstood something in your question?

Comment: @manassehcoder I've updated my answer to include a running codesandbox demo if there was anything that was unclear.

Comment: @manassehcoder What is the challenge/issue with using the API now? Is this a new/separate issue from question here regarding adding/updating cart items? It would be preferable to ask a new on-topic question than to debug here in comments. If you post a new question feel free to ping me here in comment with a link to it, and I'll take a look when available.