# How can I replace UUID details with a working API Data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to replace some code one this application with actual working API data without breaking the code. I have had someone help from the community to have the cart page working.

I have cleaned the code into reusable components. But I am struggling adding the new data from the API replacing the one in here. Below I have attached the App code and the sample of the data I need to add.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useParams,
  Link,
  generatePath
} from "react-router-dom";
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from "uuid";

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71923595/how-can-i-add-the-item-to-cart-page-in-react
 */

const Home = () => <h1>Home</h1>;

function ItemDetail({ handleClick, products }) {
  const { productCode, vendor, value } = useParams();
  // const item = { productCode, vendor, value };
  const item = products.find((item) => item.productCode === productCode);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>product id: {item.productCode}</p>
      <p>Description: {item.value}</p>
      <p>vendor: {item.vendor}</p>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(item)}>Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const Cart = ({ cart, setCart, handleChange }) => {
  const handleRemove = (productCode) => {
    setCart((cart) => cart.filter((item) => item.productCode !== productCode));
  };

  const price = cart.reduce(
    (total, item) => total + item.amount * item.price,
    0
  );

  return (
    <article>
      {cart.map((item) => (
        <div className="cart_box" key={item.id}>
          <p>{item.value}</p>
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => handleChange(item.productCode, 1)}>+</button>
            <button>{item.amount}</button>
            <button onClick={() => handleChange(item.productCode, -1)}>
              -
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>{item.price}</span>
            <button onClick={() => handleRemove(item.productCode)}>
              Remove
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <div className="total">
        <span>Total Price of your Cart</span>
        <span>R - {price}</span>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
};

**const data = Array.from({ length: 50 }, () => ({
  productCode: uuidV4(),
  value: `product ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}`,
  vendor: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 100).toString(),
  price: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) / 100
}));**

const Products = ({ products }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <ul>
        {products.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.productCode}>
            <Link
              to={generatePath("/itemDetail/:productCode/:value/:vendor", item)}
            >
              {item.value}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts(data);
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (item) => {
    if (cart.some((cartItem) => cartItem.productCode === item.productCode)) {
      setCart((cart) =>
        cart.map((cartItem) =>
          cartItem.productCode === item.productCode
            ? {
                ...cartItem,
                amount: cartItem.amount + 1
              }
            : cartItem
        )
      );
      return;
    }

    setCart((cart) => [
      ...cart,
      { ...item, amount: 1 } // <-- initial amount 1
    ]);
  };

  const handleChange = (productCode, d) => {
    setCart((cart) =>
      cart.flatMap((cartItem) =>
        cartItem.productCode === productCode
          ? cartItem.amount + d < 1
            ? [] // <-- remove item if amount will be less than 1
            : [
                {
                  ...cartItem,
                  amount: cartItem.amount + d
                }
              ]
          : [cartItem]
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/products">Products</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/cart">Cart</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          {/* <Route path="all-categories" element={<AllCategories />} />
          <Route path="entertainment" element={<Entertainment />} />
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="discover" element={<Discover />} />
          <Route path="netflix" element={<Netflix />} />
          <Route path="orders" element={<Orders />} />
          <Route path="sign-up" element={<SignUp />} /> */}
          <Route path="products" element={<Products products={products} />} />
          <Route
            path="/itemDetail/:productCode/:value/:vendor"
            element={
              <ItemDetail products={products} handleClick={handleClick} />
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/Cart/"
            element={
              <Cart cart={cart} setCart={setCart} handleChange={handleChange} />
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here below is what I am getting from the API I am trying to add.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
                "Description": "Jame Deff",
                "Vendor": "Sony Play Station",
                "VendorId": 20,
                "FaceValue": 50,
                "DefaultCost": 50,
                "ProductCode": 317,
                "Name": 50,
                "ProductCodeAlt": "FLASH-317",
                "ProductTypeEnum": "Wallet Top Up",
                "ProductStatusEnum": "Active",
                "CountryId": 179,
                "Country": "South Africa",
                "CountryAlpha2Code": "27",
                "createdAt": "2022-05-03T12:08:43.718Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T09:55:47.328Z",
                "publishedAt": "2022-05-03T12:08:47.100Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "attributes": {
                "Description": "R1 - R2500 1Voucher Token",
                "Vendor": "1 Voucher",
                "VendorId": 9,
                "FaceValue": 0,
                "DefaultCost": 0,
                "ProductCode": 311,
                "Name": null,
                "ProductCodeAlt": "FLASH-311",
                "ProductTypeEnum": "Token",
                "ProductStatusEnum": "Active",
                "CountryId": 179,
                "Country": "South Africa",
                "CountryAlpha2Code": "27",
                "createdAt": "2022-05-03T12:29:58.102Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-03T12:30:00.609Z",
                "publishedAt": "2022-05-03T12:30:00.607Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "attributes": {
                "Description": "Refund 1Voucher Token",
                "Vendor": "1 Voucher",
                "VendorId": 9,
                "FaceValue": 0,
                "DefaultCost": 0,
                "ProductCode": 392,
                "Name": null,
                "ProductCodeAlt": "FLASH-392",
                "ProductTypeEnum": "Token",
                "ProductStatusEnum": "Active",
                "CountryId": 179,
                "Country": "South Africa",
                "CountryAlpha2Code": "27",
                "createdAt": "2022-05-03T12:33:12.421Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-03T12:33:14.089Z",
                "publishedAt": "2022-05-03T12:33:14.087Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 3
        }
    }
}
```

Below here, is how I am fetching my API

```
 const [Alldata, setAlldata] = useState([]); // <-- array

  useEffect(() => {
    // GET request using fetch inside useEffect React hook
    fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/rows/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(({ data }) => setAlldata(data)); // <-- save the data array
  }, []);
```

My intention is to also keep using productCode as my identifier

Answer (score 0):

> My intention is to also keep using productCode as my identifier

It looks like the data you are consuming and rendering is nested in the response data's `attributes` property. You can "pre-process" the response data before enqueueing a state update to flatten the data a bit.

Example:

```js
const response = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
                "Description": "Jame Deff",
                "Vendor": "Sony Play Station",
                "VendorId": 20,
                "FaceValue": 50,
                "DefaultCost": 50,
                "ProductCode": 317,
                "Name": 50,
                "ProductCodeAlt": "FLASH-317",
                "ProductTypeEnum": "Wallet Top Up",
                "ProductStatusEnum": "Active",
                "CountryId": 179,
                "Country": "South Africa",
                "CountryAlpha2Code": "27",
                "createdAt": "2022-05-03T12:08:43.718Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-04T09:55:47.328Z",
                "publishedAt": "2022-05-03T12:08:47.100Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "attributes": {
                "Description": "R1 - R2500 1Voucher Token",
                "Vendor": "1 Voucher",
                "VendorId": 9,
                "FaceValue": 0,
                "DefaultCost": 0,
                "ProductCode": 311,
                "Name": null,
                "ProductCodeAlt": "FLASH-311",
                "ProductTypeEnum": "Token",
                "ProductStatusEnum": "Active",
                "CountryId": 179,
                "Country": "South Africa",
                "CountryAlpha2Code": "27",
                "createdAt": "2022-05-03T12:29:58.102Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-03T12:30:00.609Z",
                "publishedAt": "2022-05-03T12:30:00.607Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "attributes": {
                "Description": "Refund 1Voucher Token",
                "Vendor": "1 Voucher",
                "VendorId": 9,
                "FaceValue": 0,
                "DefaultCost": 0,
                "ProductCode": 392,
                "Name": null,
                "ProductCodeAlt": "FLASH-392",
                "ProductTypeEnum": "Token",
                "ProductStatusEnum": "Active",
                "CountryId": 179,
                "Country": "South Africa",
                "CountryAlpha2Code": "27",
                "createdAt": "2022-05-03T12:33:12.421Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-03T12:33:14.089Z",
                "publishedAt": "2022-05-03T12:33:14.087Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 3
        }
    }
}

const allData = response.data.map(({ id, attributes }) => ({
  id,
  ...attributes,
}));

console.log(allData);
```

Code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // GET request using fetch inside useEffect React hook
  fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/rows/")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(({ data }) => {
      const allData = data.map(({ id, attributes }) => ({
        id,
        ...attributes,
      }))
      setAlldata(allData);
    });
}, []);
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-replace-uuid-details-with-a-working-api-data]

Comment: I am unable to change the structure of the API data I am consuming. My intention is to use as it is. But not use the UUID and use real data. I have tried changing the useEffect where we set Data to All data. But still it doe not now. How can I remove that UUID completely and use the API data?

Comment: @manassehcoder Perhaps I've misunderstood something. This answer does use the real data you provided, and it removed the UUID. Use the `id` property in place of any previous UUID you were using.

Comment: const data = Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => ({
  productCode: uuidV4(),
  value: `product ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}`,
  vendor: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 100).toString(),
  price: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) / 100,
}));

This is what it looks like. If I change that productCode: uuidV4(),
to productCode: id,

it tells me id is not defined. and there is a useEffect setProducts to (data), but my data is called AllData. When I rename it, the data does not return

Comment: @manassehcoder The `response.data` replaces the `data` from your previous question where we had to generate generic data to render. I took the liberty of camelCasing all the generic data's properties, but you'll need to fix these references so the UI can access the data properties correctly. https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-replace-uuid-details-with-a-working-api-data-bf0qfi

Comment: Thank you Drew, I see this is working. But your response is an object physically embedded into the code. I am trying to use allData from the API. 

I do not know how to explain this.

That data you have made the response. How would I use where it if it was in an external file. Maybe that would make sense....

I have fetched the the data again and tried saying const response = allData. But that wont work

Comment: @manassehcoder The code in my example simulates the fetch as closely as is possible without *actually* fetching it since I don't have the backend. In other words, I've mocked  the API request and subbed your valid response object. The fetching part isn't relevant though. The change you need to make is to "flatten" the response data.

Comment: https://github.com/oneziki/ecomm_copy.git

Please find the source code here. Use. npm run develop to start the backend

Comment: Please note that for the backend to work, you must be using Node JS above v12